# WCF custom UserNameValidator - When and where in the channel mode is this added?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I need to access the EndPoint on a service before UserNamePassword valdiation is done. I am having a custom usernamepasswordvalidator. Before this authentication i need to access the endpoint. I tried implementing messageinspector,iservicehbevaior etc but all of them seems to be hit only after UserNamePassword validation. Is there any extensibility point before UserNamePassword validation that would allow me to access the EndPoint?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of processing do you want to do before UserNamePassword validation is done?

A few things I can think of:

- Create a custom channel, and then a custom binding that injects this channel between the transport and the security channels
- Create a custom encoder that wraps the built-in (text, binary, etc.) encoder that you're using

Comment: I just need to acces the endpoint before authentication is done. I guess writing a custom channle or an encoder might be an overkill here.But i'll definitely give custom encoder a go until i get a better way to do it.